# How to make ExtJs DatePicker in my MVC site?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, extjs, datepicker

I need a datepicker widget via ExtJs on my pages that  [works like this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

All I found in ExtJs are
DatePicker and [This sample with pickers](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/adv-vtypes.html)

The problem is that standart DatePicker looks like just a huge calendar with "today" button.  The sample gives picker that looks like i want(textbox field and calendar on demand) but it works in the panel here. I don't want to create panel just to show one datepicker. This sample match very well - i need startdate and enddate too, but this panel is sux. I just want two separate pickers without any panel.

As I know the idea of standart datepicker is that you create textbox on your page and then you make a ExtJs script where you show datepicker on textbox click or something like this.

I'm not expert in ExtJs could anybody show the sample how to work with dates via ExtJs in Asp Net MVC ?

Comment: Can't you just hide the "panel" using CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want the `Today` button in your datepickers you just have to use the [`showToday` config option](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.DateField&member=showToday) on the datePicker creation.

And for the DatePickers not to be inside panels, just don't use the `FormPanel` in the example and create the datePickers defining the [`applyTo` config option](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Component&member=applyTo):

```
var startdt = new Ext.form.DateField({
    applyTo: 'tbStartDt', // <-- here you say where it must be rendered
    fieldLabel: 'Start Date',
    name: 'startdt',
    id: 'startdt',
    vtype: 'daterange',
    endDateField: 'enddt', // id of the end date field
    showToday: false
});

var enddt = new Ext.form.DateField({
    applyTo: 'tbEndDt', // <-- here you say where it must be rendered
    fieldLabel: 'End Date',
    name: 'enddt',
    id: 'enddt',
    vtype: 'daterange',
    startDateField: 'startdt', // id of the start date field
    showToday: false
});
```

Then your `html` page will need to have the 2 inputs with ids: `tbStartDt` and `tbEndDt` that we defined above:

```
Start Date: <input id="tbStartDt"></input>
End Date: <input id="tbEndDt"></input>
```

You can test the example I made in [jsfiddle.net/CrfvC/26/](http://jsfiddle.net/CrfvC/26/).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your sample realy helps me.

Comment: I know this is late.. but will this still work in Ext JS 4.2?

Comment: @rahsta9 Yes it does. Just check the jsfiddle I posted and change the imported Ext JS version and you'll see it working with the new date fields.